# iPad Pages Password Protection

Tags: ipad, password, pages, iwork

I've read that pages on iPad can access protected files created on Pages (mac).  Can you also edit the files on iPad, or are they locked?  If you can edit the files, do they become unlocked, or do they retain the protection.

It would be great if someone could enlighten me on the nature of password protection (in iWork apps) on the iPad. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the protected files by entering the password.  However, you will get the warning that by opening the document it will become a Pages for iOS document, and thus will no longer be password protected.  You do have the option of 'Opening a Copy' thereby preserving the originals password.

This could be useful if you just need access to the document to read it and then deleting the copy.  Not so useful if you need to edit the doc and save it and have the password intact.